# How to get productID from OpportunityLineItem in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am having a trigger let's say

```
trigger triggerX on opportunityLineItem(before insert, before update){
  //Calling a method 
    ClassX.MethodX(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap)
}

In Class we have that perticular method:

public static void MethodX(List<OpportunityLineItem> oliIn, Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> oldOliMap){

// I have created a set
 Set<Id> prodSet = new Set<Id>();

//in above set I want to add all productID of all incoming opportunity request(Trigger.new)
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : oliIn) {
   if(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2Id != null){
      prodSet.add(oli.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
   }
}

}
```

But oli.PricebookEntry.Product2Id is giving me null value.

Is there any other way so that I can add product ID of Trigger.new request of opportuniLineItem object to a Set

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are getting parameter as Opportunity in methodX,
Have a look for following code, it will work:

```
Set<Id> prodSet =  new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [Select Id, PricebookEntryId  FROM OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId in :oppySet]){
     ids.add(oli.PricebookEntryId);
}
for(PricebookEntry pbe : [Select Id, Product2Id, Product2.Id from PricebookEntry where id in :ids]) {
     prodSet.add(pbe.Product2.Id);
}
System.debug('prodSet:: '+prodSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve...

You can't get product2Id from opportunity insert action - that's because at this moment there are no products.

If you realy need Information about product2 use OpportunityLineItem trigger.

Comment: Yes it was opportunityLineItem. Mistakenly I have wriiten Opportunity